Step functions removing null values from JSON while executing a task state
Step functions currently ignore null values in the json and its very weird. Example: Say we passed an input to a state which is say calling an API gateway to say a microservice.
Sample Step function:
{
    "StartAt": "Pass to Microservice",
    "States": {
        "Pass to Microservice": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::apigateway:invoke",
            "Parameters": {
                "ApiEndpoint":"somename.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
                "Method":"POST",
                "Stage":"Prod",
                "Path":"${microservice-path}",
                "RequestBody": {
                    "firstName.$": "$.firstName",
                    "lastName.$": "$.lastName",
                    "email.$": "$.email",
                    "birthDate.$": "$.dateOfBirth"
                }
            },
            "Next": "No Action"
        },
        "No Action": {
            "Type": "Pass",
            "End": true
        }
    }
}

Input to state:
{
  "firstName" : "firstName",
  "lastName" : "lastName", 
  "email" : "email@email.com",
  "dateOfBirth" : null
}

When the microservice will receive the json it will receive
{
  "firstName" : "firstName",
  "lastName" : "lastName", 
  "email" : "email@email.com"
}

Which is very weird as step functions is removing this silently. The step function console on AWS doesn't indicate this anywhere. It will show the task input as JSON with null values and under the hood it removes them.
Anyone knows the solutions to this and how we can prevent trimming/removing null values from JSON?

Only one document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-api-gateway.html has a solution to this problem and hardly we will find any thing similar on Stack overflow. In our case we reached out to AWS Support team as well but they also didn't mention anything similar to us.
Ultimately we have to pass a flag called AllowNullValues as true while defining the state in a step function.
Example:
{
    "StartAt": "Pass to Microservice",
    "States": {
        "Pass to Microservice": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::apigateway:invoke",
            "Parameters": {
                "ApiEndpoint":"somename.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
                "Method":"POST",
                "Stage":"Prod",
                "Path":"${microservice-path}",
                "RequestBody": {
                    "firstName.$": "$.firstName",
                    "lastName.$": "$.lastName",
                    "email.$": "$.email",
                    "birthDate.$": "$.dateOfBirth"
                }
            },
            "Next": "No Action"
        },
        "No Action": {
            "Type": "Pass",
            "End": true
        }
    }
}

gets input as
{
  "firstName" : "firstName",
  "lastName" : "lastName", 
  "email" : "email@email.com",
  "dateOfBirth" : null
}

then the microservice will receive following json:
{
  "firstName" : "firstName",
  "lastName" : "lastName", 
  "email" : "email@email.com"
}

This can only be fixed if we change the state machine definition to
{
    "StartAt": "Pass to Microservice",
    "States": {
        "Pass to Microservice": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::apigateway:invoke",
            "Parameters": {
                "ApiEndpoint":"somename.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
                "Method":"POST",
                "Stage":"Prod",
                "Path":"${microservice-path}",
                "AllowNullValue" : true,
                "RequestBody": {
                    "firstName.$": "$.firstName",
                    "lastName.$": "$.lastName",
                    "email.$": "$.email",
                    "birthDate.$": "$.dateOfBirth"
                }
            },
            "Next": "No Action"
        },
        "No Action": {
            "Type": "Pass",
            "End": true
        }
    }
}

Adding this so that others don't spend too much time on this.

Thank you for the answer. This (removal of nulls) was unexpected behavior when we launched this integration. But by the time we realized it, we changing the default would have been a breaking change so we decided to add this additional flag. I will talk with the team to see if we can improve visibility in the docs and have this set by default to true when creating in Workflow Studio. Apologies for the confusion.

Thanks @JustinCallison. One suggestion is put this in some example. Specially in the starting of the documentation so that its more visible. For us its sorted now. Hopefully others find this post useful.

The docs have been updated and our doc writer included an example in addition to a note to make this more prominent: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-api-gateway.html#connect-api-gateway-requests

@JustinCallison Thanks for making the changes. I do see the default behaviour has been mentioned now. Which is really good and helpful. It would still be nice we we can have one example. May be I am asking too much for my fellow developers. May be add one more example here -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-api-gateway.html#connect-api-gateway-patterns. Where we explicitly state that this is how you can allow null values in a put/post call.
